# Записать значения textField1 в память для последующего сравнения в другом view

Tags: swift, mobile-development

Есть `view` с `textField`. Надо записать введенное в него значение и сравнить со значением другого `textField` из другого `view`. Записать желательно на все время, а не на время исполнения программы.

Я так понимаю, для этих целей надо поднимать бд и прикручивать `view` к ней?

Comment: Слушайте, вы бы ответы на прошлые 8 вопросов приняли бы

Comment: Как их принять?

Comment: нажать галочку возле понравившегося ответа

Comment: а второй аккаунт? (я так понимаю Игорь Иванов это тоже вы)

Comment: Да. Там тоже сделал!

Comment: NSUserDefaults, например

Comment: А можно пример кода?)

Comment: Я разобрался как это делать в поле одного класса, но как передать эту информацию в поле другого класса?

Answer (score 1):

Привожу ниже пример программы с использованием хранилища UserDefaults.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let kSomeKey = "SomeKey"

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!

    // сохраняем текст, введеный в textField1, "на все время"
    @IBAction func btnSaveAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let text1 = textField1.text
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        userDefaults.set(text1, forKey: kSomeKey)
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    }

    // считываем текст, который был введен в textField1 и сохранен сейчас
    // или в прошлом сеансе работы программы, и сравниваем его с текстом в textField2, находящемся в другом view
    @IBAction func btnCompareAction(_ sender: Any) {
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let text1 = userDefaults.string(forKey: kSomeKey)!
        let text2 = textField2.text!
        if text1 == text2 {
            lblResult.text = "Результат: значение, сохраненное ранее в textField1 (\(text1)) равно значению в textField2 (\(text2))"
        } else {
            lblResult.text = "Результат: значение, сохраненное ранее в textField1 (\(text1)) не равно значению в textField2 (\(text2))"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Да, если вам нужно сохранять много данных, то тогда нужно использовать базу данных. Можно воспользоваться `UserDefaults` для сохранения данных по определенному ключу. Более подробно о `UserDefaults` в документации [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

Все зависит от того, что именно вам нужно сделать.